# Kendo Grid FilterMenu

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to configure the filtermenu of my grid to use "contains" as default filter option.

Here are my settings. But this does not change the deafult filter option (the extra option work as expected)!

```
.Filterable(filter =>
 {
     filter.Extra(false);
     filter.Operators(op =>
     {
         op.ForString(str =>
         {
             str.Clear();
             str.Contains("Contains");
         });
     });
 })
```

Complete View:

```
@using NursingHomeStock.Resources
@{
    ViewBag.Title = GlobalResources.EmploymentStatus;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NursingHomeStock.Models.EmployeeEmploymentStatusViewModel>()
      .Name("EmploymentStatusGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(m => m.EmploymentStatusId).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(m => m.FirstName);
          columns.Bound(m => m.LastName);
          columns.Bound(e => e.From).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
          columns.Bound(e => e.To).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
          columns.Bound(e => e.ContractPercent).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format(\"{0:p}\", ContractPercent / 100)#"); //.EditorTemplateName("NumberPercent");
          columns.Bound(e => e.MarginalEmployment)
              .ClientTemplate("#=(MarginalEmployment) ? '" + GlobalResources.True +
                              "' : '" + GlobalResources.False +
                              "' #")
              .EditorTemplateName("DropDownListBoolean");
          //columns.Bound(e => e.Qualification).ClientTemplate("#=Qualification.Name#");
          columns.Bound(m => m.QualificationName);// .Filterable(f => f.Extra(false).Operators(o => o.ForString(s => s.Contains("Contains"))));
          columns.Command(command => command.Custom(GlobalResources.Edit).Click("App.EmploymentStatus.openEditModal"));
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Template(@<text>
                <div>
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="App.EmploymentStatus.openCreateModal('@ViewBag.nursingHomeId')">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> @GlobalResources.Create
                    </button>
                    @*
                        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick=" App.EmploymentStatus.saveChanges(); ">
                            <span class="fa fa-save"></span> @GlobalResources.Save
                        </button>
                    *@
                    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                            .Name("ForDate")
                            .Value(DateTime.Now)
                            )
                    @GlobalResources.All <input id="all-employment-statuses" type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick=" App.EmploymentStatus.refresh(); ">
                        <span class="fa fa-refresh"></span> @GlobalResources.Refresh
                    </button>
                </div>
            </text>);
      })
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable
          .Refresh(true)
          .PageSizes(new[] {5, 10, 20, 50, 100})
          .ButtonCount(5))
      .Sortable()
      // TODO: set default filter operator to [contains]
      .Filterable(filter => filter
          .Extra(false)
          .Operators(op => op.ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .Contains("Contains")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("App.errorHandler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.EmploymentStatusId);
            model.Field(m => m.FirstName).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.LastName).Editable(false);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmployeeEmploymentStatus", "Employee", new { ViewBag.nursingHomeId}).Data("App.EmploymentStatus.getFilter"))
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("LastName").Ascending())
    )
    .Events(events => events.Edit("App.EmploymentStatus.onEdit"))
)



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-create-employment-status" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-create-employment-status-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-create-employment-status-label">@GlobalResources.Create</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="form-create-employment-status" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                    <input type="hidden" id="employment-status-id" name="employment-status-id" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dropdown-employee" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.Employee</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="" id="dropdown-employee" name="employee" required=""/>
                            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="dropdown-employee"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="from" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.From *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "" })
                                      .Name("from")
                                      .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
                            )
                            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="from"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="to" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.To</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                                  .Name("to")
                                  .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
                                  )
                            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="to"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="marginal-employment" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.MarginalEmployment</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input id="marginal-employment" type="checkbox" class="" name="marginal-employment">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount-of-employment" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.AmountOfEmployment</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
                                  .IncreaseButtonTitle(GlobalResources.Increase)
                                  .DecreaseButtonTitle(GlobalResources.Decrease)
                                  .Name("amount-of-employment")
                                  //.Format("p")
                                  .Format("{0:# \\%}")
                                  .Min(0)
                                  .Max(100)
                                  )
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dropdown-qualification" class="col-sm-4 control-label">@GlobalResources.Qualification</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="" id="dropdown-qualification" name="qualification" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@GlobalResources.Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#form-create-employment-status').submit();">@GlobalResources.Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        App.EmploymentStatus.nursingHomeId = '@(ViewBag.nursingHomeId)';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (remove filters not applicable for you):

Kendo MVC:

```
.Filterable(filter => filter
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(op => op
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
        .Contains("Contains")
        .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
        .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
    ))
)
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
filterable: {
    extra: false,
    operators: {
        string: {
            Contains: "Contains",
            eq: "Is equal to",
            neq: "Is not equal to"
        }
    }
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msc20fjn/

Comment: I've added a fiddle showing Contains as the default filter. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: That is exact that what I need, but it does not work for me, i have the FilterMenu in German is it possible that the german translation procedure is overriding my local settings?

Comment: Could you add the complete code you're using for the grid?